# User session deletes after page reload - React / Passport

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-context

I am trying to set up a user authentication app using MERN.

- I have a Registration component which is storing data to MongoDB.
- A login compopnent which is authenticating using PassportJS
  successfully and redirecting to Dashboard component.

The problem is, the user session goes away if I reload Dashboard.

This is the user state post successful login and it goes away post reload:

```js
{
    "id":"5ef121f56ea4d5299f25f2d5",
    "name":"John Doe",
    "email":"john@gmail.com",
    "iat":1593119338,
    "exp":1624676264
}
```

This is a working code I found out on a blog post, which I believe should work. But that particular app was using Redux and I am using Context. So I am unable to make this code work.

This code will go to React App.js file:

```js
// Check for token to keep user logged in
if (localStorage.jwtToken) {
  // Set auth token header auth
  const token = localStorage.jwtToken;
  setAuthToken(token);
  // Decode token and get user info and exp
  const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
  // Set user and isAuthenticated
  store.dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded));
  // Check for expired token
  const currentTime = Date.now() / 1000; // to get in milliseconds
  if (decoded.exp < currentTime) {
    // Logout user
    store.dispatch(logoutUser());
    // Redirect to login
    window.location.href = './login';
  }
}
```

Now where I am stuck:

I can make it work till `const decoded = jwt_decode(token);`, and I am stuck in here `store.dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded));`

- Because I am using context, I don't have a store to call.
- I can't directly use dispatch as Reducer.js will not work until it is called inside a function.
- I can't call `setCurrentUser(decoded)` function as this function is defined inside context Provider function and not exported individually.

Can someone please point out to me what can I do here??

This is my GlobalContext.js file which consists of the above function:

```
// Initial State
const initialState = {
  user: [],
  loading: true,
  isAuthenticated: false,
};

// Create Context
export const GlobalContext = createContext(initialState);

// Provider Component

export const GlobalProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(AppReducer, initialState);

  // Action

  // Register User
  function registerUser(userData, history) {
    axios
      .post('/api/users/register', userData)
      .then((res) => history.push('/login')) // re-direct to login on successful register
      .catch((err) =>
        // dispatch({
        //   type: 'GET_ERRORS',
        //   payload: err,
        // })
        console.log(err)
      );
  }

  // Set Auth Token
  const setAuthToken = (token) => {
    if (token) {
      // Apply authorization token to every request if logged in
      axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token;
    } else {
      // Delete auth header
      delete axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'];
    }
  };

  // Get User Token
  function loginUser(userdata) {
    axios
      .post('/api/users/login', userdata)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data.token);
        const { token } = res.data;
        localStorage.setItem('jwtToken', token);
        setAuthToken(token);
        const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
        console.log(decoded);
        dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded));
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        // dispatch({
        //   type: 'GET_ERRORS',
        //   payload: err.response.data,
        // });
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

  // Set logged in user
  const setCurrentUser = (decoded) => {
    return {
      type: 'SET_CURRENT_USER',
      payload: decoded,
    };
  };

  //Log User Out
  function logoutUser() {
    // Remove token from local storage
    localStorage.removeItem('jwtToken');
    // Remove auth header for future requests
    setAuthToken(false);
    // Set current user to empty object {} which will set isAuthenticated to false
    dispatch(setCurrentUser({}));
    window.location.href = '/login';
  }

  
  return (
    <GlobalContext.Provider
      value={{
        user: state.user,
        loading: state.loading,
        isAuthenticated: state.isAuthenticated,
        registerUser,
        loginUser,
        setCurrentUser,
        logoutUser,
        setUserLoading,
        setAuthToken,
        addMonitor,
        getMonitors,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </GlobalContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

This is my app.js. I can't call Conditional inside , hence I am unable to use functions (dispatch, setCurrentUser & logoutUser) which is in the above globalcontext.js file.

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <GlobalProvider>
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <Navbar />
          <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
          <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
          <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
          {/* <Switch>
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
          </Switch> */}
          <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
        </div>
      </Router>
    </GlobalProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: `<GlobalContext.Provider
      value={{dispatch, other values`

Comment: This will not work. I have updated the question and added my app.js below and reason why your solution won't work. But thanks for letting me know that dispatch also can be exported through Value.

Comment: You could do `<GlobalProvider><App /></<GlobalProvider>` in src/index

Comment: I added `const { logoutUser, dispatch, setCurrentUser } = useContext(GlobalContext);` on `App.js` before `function App()`, and then my if statement.

But I am getting error : Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

The error is because I am calling useContext outside of Function App()

Comment: and If I set both useContext and if conditional inside the function App(), I get this error: Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

Comment: What if you dispatch it only on mount by putting it in an effect?

Comment: This is working now. But I need to setup a loading on Dashboard, so that there is a delay in fetching data from state while the data is being loaded on the state post reload.

Comment: @HMR I set up React suspense on App.js and loading is working, but still, If I reload Dashboard it wont fetch data from state, whereas state is being updated with logged in user info. I am not sure why? I think I need to delay Dashboard rendering. What do you think?